# Class definition conventions in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, convention

I'm quite new to programming so I'm trying to learn good programming practices now from the start, I have a question regarding classes and source files in C#. Is the convention to always define each class in a seperate source file? Or is it dependant on the inheritance of the class? Let's say I have `Class Vehicle`, `Class Car : Vehicle` and `Class Airplane : Vehicle` would the convention then be to have them all in one source files (i.e "Vehicles.cs" or alike) since they inherit from the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is to create separate file for each class.

Answer (score 0):

Having known what @Ehsan says, you can then use the same `namespace` for any one hierarchy of inheritance and thus different `namespaces` for different hierarchies to distinguish between the parent classes or interfaces.

e.g.

Hierarchy 1:

```
Interface1
|- class1
|- class2
```

For this hierarchy, you can set namespace like `<ProjectName>.RelevantName1` in each of the class/interface definition files.

Hierarchy 2:

```
BaseClass1
|- ChildClass1
|- ChildClass2
```

For this hierarchy, you can set namespace like `<ProjectName>.RelevantName2` in each of the class/interface definition files.